# Unix : Integer expression expected

Tags: bash, unix

```
#!/bin/bash

location=$1
englishCount=0
bourneCount=0
CShellCount=0
symbolicCount=0
emptyCount=0
dirCount=0

if [ ! $# -eq 1 ]; then
echo Need to supply one argument
exit
fi

if [ ! -d $1 ]; then
echo Directory not found
exit
fi


find $location | while read item
do
if [-f "$item" ]
then
    if [ "file $loc/* | grep English | wc -l" -eq 1 ]
        then
        $englishCount=$[englishCount+1]
    elif [ "file $loc/* | grep Bourne | wc -l" -eq 1 ]
        then
        $bourneCount=$[bourneCount+1]
    elif [ "file $loc/* | grep C.Shell | wc -l" -eq 1 ]
        then
        $CShellCount=$[$CShellCount+1]
    elif [ "file $loc/* | grep symbolic | wc -l" -eq 1 ]
        then
        $symbolicCount=$[$symbolicCount+1 ]
    elif
        $emptyCount=$[$emptyCount+1 ]  
elif [ -d "$item" ]
then
    dirCount=$[dirCount+1]
fi
done

echo "English count: " $englishCount
echo "bourne count: " $bourneCount
echo "CShell count: " $CShellCount
echo "symbolic count : " $symbolicCount
echo "empty count: " $emptyCount
echo "Directory count: " $dirCount
```

I'm trying to create a script to sort the contents of a directory by type but, I get an error saying that Integer expression expected. IM under the impression that the expression used to compare to the integer one would result in a numeric value but, my script does not recognize it as such.

Comment: You are comparing a string with a number. You need to use back ticks to evaluate the first part of the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
if [ "file $loc/* | grep English | wc -l" -eq 1 ]
```

You are comparing a string with a number.  Instead try

```
if [ `file $loc/* | grep English | wc -l` -eq 1 ]
```

The back ticks cause "the thing between them" to be run as a subprocess, with the result returned to this program. And then the "string" that is returned (some numeric output from `wc -l` ) is turned into an integer and compared with `1`.

Obviously you have do to this to all similar instances.

Comment: Glad it did. You can now hit the little check mark to the left to show this is the correct answer.